# A complex integral $\int_\gamma \frac{\text dz}{z-a}=\int_\gamma \text d\;\log(z-a)=\int_\gamma \text d\;\log|z-a|+i\int_\gamma \text d\;\arg(z-a)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int \frac{dz}{z-a}＝\int d\log(z-a)＝\int d\log|z-a|+i\int d\arg(z-a)$$

I want to know why the last step has an extra imaginary part after adding the absolute value to $z-a$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) + [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.

Comment: Do you know how we define, e.g., $\log(i+1)$?

Comment: I'm not quite clear

Comment: @tianhaowu The logarithm of a complex number $c$ is defined to be set of all complex numbers $a$ such that $\exp(a)=c$. It follows that there is an arbitrary choice of argument because $e^{2\pi i}= 1$